# How do I see my dota 2 MMR?

Tags: dota-2

Is there a way to see my MMR? The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the patch 7.07 "Dueling Fates", released on November 22, 2017, the rating system got reworked.

This means that you won't see your rating in your profile or at the Find Match tab anymore.

You can still find both your Solo and Party ratings by opening your ingame user profile, and selecting the "Stats" tab. Both ratings are listed on the upper right side.

[image: Dota user profile stats tab]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can edit your profile, so that it is always shown, when you look at your profile.

When you click on "Edit Profile", there are two dropdown list, right next to the edit button.

[image: Profile Page]
(nevermind the fact, that I'm playing with the german client)

When there are no numbers, that means that you have not played enough games in either ranked solo or group (in my case, I did not play enough ranked solo, for my mmr to show up)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how:

1. Open the new (Reborn) game client.
2. Click your name, top right.

   [image: step 1]
3. Click `Edit Profile`, top right.

   [image: step 2]
4. Choose the two MMR options:

   [image: step 3]
5. Hit save!

There's now to boxes where you can showcase things, amongst which your solo and party mmr.

Comment: You can also see it in the "Play Dota" menu when selecting Ranked Game.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to click "Play Dota" then select the "Ranked Match" tab.  You don't have to actually play a game, but it should tell you your MMR there.